# Посоветуйте ресурсы для изучения линукса

Tags: linux

Пожалуйста посоветуйте ресурсы где можно научиться пользоваться линуксом. Желательно, чтобы в этих ресурсах были задачи, которые нужно решить используя линукс (что на подобии проекта Эйлера).

Comment: Что значит "научиться пользоваться"? Кому-то достаточно научиться там ставить пакеты и настраивать свистелки, а кому-то подавай полное руководство по доработке ядра.

Comment: Вы имелли виду операционную систему GNU ?

Comment: Да я имел в виду  GNU.

Comment: @matz, а какие ещё есть варианты кроме GNU Linux? Просто GNU OS — это Hurd.

Comment: @Arhad GNU OS - Это не Hurd. Hurd - отдельное ядро, как и Linux.